# Delete Node Function in BST

Tags: c, data-structures, tree, binary-search-tree

I have this basic implementation of a binary search tree. I encounter a problem when I try to delete a node in the tree.

In the example below, the only value I can delete is 80. I have first inserted some values in the BST without user input, and that part is working fine. I use an inorder traversal for traversing the binary tree, which also works fine. But when I try to delete the node with value 14, it fails.

Where is my error?

```
#include<stdbool.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>


struct bst {
    int data ;
    struct bst *left ;
    struct bst *right ;
};
 
 
struct bst *findmax(struct bst *root){
    if(root==NULL){
        return NULL ;
    }
    else if(root->right==NULL){
         return root ;
    }
    else return(findmax(root->right)) ;
}
 
struct bst *insertnode(struct bst *root,int data){
    if(root==NULL){
        root = (struct bst*)malloc(sizeof(struct bst)) ;
        if(root==NULL){
            printf("memory error") ;
        }
        else{
            root->data = data ;
            root->left = NULL ;
            root->right= NULL ;
        }
    }
    else{
        if(data < root->data){
            root->left = insertnode(root->left,data) ;
        }
        else if(data > root->data){
            root->right = insertnode(root->right,data) ;
        }
    }
    return root ; 
}
 
struct bst *deletenode(struct bst *root,int data){
    struct bst *temp ;
    if(root==NULL){
        printf("empty") ; 
    }
    else if(data < root->data){
        root->left = deletenode(root->left,data) ;
    }
    else if(data > root->data){
        root->right = deletenode(root->right,data);
    }
    else{
        if(root->left && root->right){
            temp = findmax(root->left) ;
            root->data = temp->data ;
            root->left = deletenode(root->left,root->data) ;
        }
        else{
            temp = root ;
            if(root->left==NULL){
                root = root->right ;
            }
            if(root->right==NULL){
                root = root->left ;
            }
            free(temp) ;
        }
    }
    return(root) ;
}
 
 
void traversebst(struct bst *root){
    if(root){
        traversebst(root->left);
        printf("\n%d",root->data) ;
        traversebst(root->right);
    }
}
 
 
int main()
{
    printf("Hello World"); 
    struct bst *root = NULL;
    root = insertnode(root,5) ;
    insertnode(root,14) ;
    insertnode(root,80) ;
    insertnode(root,60) ;
    insertnode(root,6) ;
    traversebst(root);
    deletenode(root,14);   //delete not working ??
    printf("....\n") ;
    traversebst(root) ;
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error is in the last few lines of `deletenode`:

```
if(root->left==NULL){
    root = root->right ;
}
if(root->right==NULL){
    root = root->left ;
}
```

If the first condition is true, then `root` might get the value `NULL`. Then the next if-condition will be an invalid reference. So you need to make it an `else if`:

```
if(root->left==NULL){
    root = root->right ;
}
else if(root->right==NULL){
    root = root->left ;
}
```

Comment: Thankyou Sir ,It worked, I  was  pondering on this problem for so long.